# Oracle : Use two different versions of EXP on the same machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dump, ora-12705

i have a server (HP-UX) installed with Oracle 10g and several databases on it.

I've been asked to make dumps from these tables for a Oracle 8i database. In order to do this, i need to use the 8i version of the EXP (export) tool of Oracle.

It is still installed on my server but when i want to use it, i get the following error :

EXP-00056: ORACLE error 12705 encountered
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

I presume some files are missing or maybe one of the folder is not in the PATH but i can't find and i really don't want to break the 10g installation.

Someone knows how to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your ORACLE_HOME set correctly?

Comment: the problem is my ORACLE_HOME is set up for Oracle 10g and i don't want to change it to the 8i folder .. How could i make both working correctly at the same time  ?

Comment: You can't have both at the same time. You can set up a wrapper shell script that sets the Oracle 8 environment then calls exp, isql etc

Comment: Sorry to ask you that but have you got an example of such a script ? i'm a bit bad in shell script and oracle and i don't want to break anything :)

Comment: I don't have one for Oracle. but how do you set your environment for 10g - from taht you can duplicate the variables and set them to the 10g version

Answer (score 0):

Install a 10G client  on another system, without modifying the 8I database server,
and connect from the client to the 8I database.  Use the export utilities on
the client to generate the export file.